# Proper writing of External JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external JS file that contains the following codes. Though its working properly, I would like to ask if the way I write my code in the file is correct

My Current Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divTest').click(function () {
        // Some Instructions Here
    });
});

function js_function_One(){
    // Some Instruction
}

function js_function_Two(){
    // Some Instruction
}
```

Or it should be this way (putting everything inside the document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divTest').click(function () {
        // Some Instructions Here
    });

    function js_function_One(){
    // Some Instruction
    }

    function js_function_Two(){
    // Some Instruction
    }
});
```

Comment: Its depend on the scenarios that you use the function. The first type is I prefer because we can call the function in both dom ready and window ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. Let' say you want the function call to take place inside the `ready` scope only, then you can do something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divTest').click(function () {
        // Some Instructions Here
    });
    function js_function_One(){
    // Some Instruction
    }

});
```

Here the call to `js_function_One()` can only be done inside `ready` function. If you want to use that function globally, you can stick with you current code. Either way, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

So the "ready" event just tells you that your document / DOM has fully loaded. In that way you can start selecting elements from the dom and be sure that everything exists. So Putting selectors in the ready function seems like a good idea.

All declarations of functions etc. don't have to be in the ready function because as the name tells you , you only declare (tell the function what to do) .. the execution itself should then be in the ready block again.

hope you have a clearer picture.